# Como colocar uma web service em uma hospedagem?

Tags: android, web-service

Tenho um projeto Android que utiliza uma Web Service, porém eu tenho que reinicar toda que for utilizar ou fazer testes, ativa-lo no Tomcat através do eclipse e as vezes quando testo em redes diferentes, tenho que mudar o ip no projeto Web Service, gostaria de saber como faço para colocar esse meu projeto em uma hospedagem fixa para eu não ter mais problemas com isso, não sei como faz, se tem que jogar todo o projeto ou mais alguma manha.

Comment: Você já contratou a hospedagem?

Comment: Se você tiver já tiver uma hospedagem, instala o tom cat no servidor e fazer deploy do WebService, ai na sua aplicação pede pra ela acessar pelo ip do servidor.

Answer (score 2):

Se você já possuir uma hospedagem, configure o ambiente para produção:

**Lado servidor :**

- Instalação do Java
- Instalação/configuração do Tom Cat
- Instalar seu Banco de dados
- Fazer deploy da sua aplicação

**Lado aplicativo :**

- Obter a nova url para comunicação ex: 192.168.0.200/WebServiceREST/app
- Realizar as transições.